# How to create a SQL function using C#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to define a function to get "order number" parameter and return "last name" of the customer.these two parameters are in different tables i am using inner join.

the errors i am getting are: Incorrect syntax near `(`.

Incorrect syntax near the keyword `RETURN`.

Must declare the scalar variable `@FindingLastName`.

my code:

```
com.CommandText = "Create function Sales.FindingLastName (@OrderNumber varchar(10)) Returns nvarchar(50) As Begin Declare @FindingLastName(Select LastName from Sales.OrderDetails INNER JOIN Sales.Customers RETURN @FindingLastName END GO)";
com.Connection = con;
MessageBox.Show(com.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
```

Comment: Why are you creating functions via code? Why don't you use simple script?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with C#. The errors you get are entirely because of invalid SQL.

Comment: i am asked to create the function via code @ Marko

Comment: you can see it in my code , i am doing the same , how do you think i can fix it?thx @ Taosique

Comment: Compare your function statement with the examples given in this link at the end : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx, I would also suggest to first run your script in SQL server than use it it as commanText, if you have to prefer this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have lot of things missed in your SQL Syntax. Have a look at below SQL Syntax Change the `ColumnName`to actual columnnames in join statement. May be you want to modify the select condition accordingly by adding `WHERE` clause.

```
Create function Sales.FindingLastName 
(@OrderNumber varchar(10))
Returns nvarchar(50) As 
Begin 
Declare @FindingLastName varchar(50) = 
(Select LastName from Sales.OrderDetails O INNER JOIN Sales.Customers C ON C.ColumnName =O.ColumnName)
RETURN @FindingLastName 
END
```

One more question You can run this only once. Once the function is created, you can't create same function again. So i doubt are you sure you want to do it this way via c#?? !!

For more details on User Defined function in SQL Refer [THIS LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)

Comment: @ Naveen thanks man , i did every changes you said the only problem is that when i run it in C# i get -1 !! why is that?

Comment: @ Parisan Run the select statement you wrote in your code directly in DB and check what it returns.

Answer (score 1):

What stands out there is the `GO`. Firstly, `GO` **is not SQL**. It only exists to tools like SSMS (etc), which use it to split a long script into separate commands. Inside an actual command, it is simply a syntax error. Consequently, `GO` can never appear inside nesting such as parenthesis, or a `BEGIN` / `END` block.

Basically, remove the `GO`.

However, it is pretty rare to use DDL inside ADO.NET, unless part of an automated schema migration tool etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no hero with SQL, but i think this should work

```sql
    Create function Sales.FindingLastName (@OrderNumber varchar(10)) 
    RETURNS nvarchar(50) 
    As 
    RETURN
    (
      Select LastName 
      from Sales.OrderDetails INNER JOIN Sales.Customers 
    );
```

Comment: Dear Remco i am writing this code of yours in C# with this format com.CommandText = "Create function Sales.FindingLastName (@OrderNumber varchar(10) RETURNS nvarchar(50) As RETURN(Select LastName   from Sales.OrderDetails INNER JOIN Sales.Customers )"; and i get the error of "incorrect syntax near RETURNS" how can i correct it?